typescript error, the expected values ​do not match the props
I have a function to get the card component in react:
const getLeagueCardComponent = (value: ELeagueVaritions) => {
    if (value === ELeagueVaritions.MATCHES) {
        return MatchesCard
    }
    else if (value === ELeagueVaritions.PLAYERS) {
        return PlayersCard
    }
    else if (value === ELeagueVaritions.TOURNAMENT) {
        return TournamentCard
    }
};

MatchesCard, PlayersCard, TournamentCard are components that expect elements in props like IMatch[], IPlayerItem[], ITournamentItem[] respectively.
I have a component in which I get a card depending on the type:
const CardComponent = getLeagueCardComponent(ELeagueVaritions.MATCHES)

    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <h3>{name}</h3>

            <CardComponent items={items as IMatch[]} />
        </div>
    );

but I am getting an error and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Type 'IMatch[]' is not assignable to type 'IMatch[] & IPlayerItem[] &
ITournamentItem[]'.   Type 'IMatch[]' is not assignable to type
'IPlayerItem[]'.
Property 'rateGroups' is missing in type 'IMatch' but required in type 'IPlayerItem'.ts(2322) index.ts(57, 5): 'rateGroups' is declared
here. index.tsx(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'items'
which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps & IProps
& IProps' (property) items: IMatch[] & IPlayerItem[] &
ITournamentItem[]

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Since we don't have access to your types and values, we can't easily test it. My guess is that you want getLeagueCardComponent to be generic, but without a [mre] that's just speculation.
